# KVC Swift 2.1 Reflection

Tags: swift, reflection, kvc

I'm attempting to implement a KVC equivalent is Swift (inspired by [David Owens)](https://gist.github.com/owensd/82af8e362273e46d70f9) using reflection.

`valueForKey` is fairly trivial, using reflection to get all the children names and retrieve the appropriate value. `setValueForKey` has proved to be quite tricky however, as Swift reflection appears to be read-only (since readwrite would break reflections dogma)

```
protocol KVC {
    var codeables: [String: Any.Type] { get }
    mutating func setValue<T>(value: T, forKey key: String)
    func getValue<T>(key: String) -> T?
}


extension KVC {
    var codeables: [String: Any.Type] {
        var dictionary: [String: Any.Type] = [:]
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in mirror.children {
            if let label = child.label {
                 dictionary[label] = Mirror(reflecting: child.value).subjectType
             }
         }
        return dictionary
    }

    mutating func setValue<T>(value: T, forKey key: String) {
        if let valueType = self.codeables[key] where valueType == value.dynamicType {

        }
    }

    func getValue<T>(key: String) -> T? {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in mirror.children {
            if let label = child.label, value = child.value as? T where label == key {
                return value
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Is there anyway in Swift at all to set a dynamic keypath value without using the Objective-C runtime or enforcing that the conformer is a subclass of `NSObject`? It seems like the answer is no but there are some clever workarounds such as [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper), although I'm not a fan of the responsibility its on the conformer.

Comment: Swifts reflection is 100% read-only, so the answer is no, you'll have to use some nasty workaround (btw reflection is super slow)

Comment: Is there a better way than reflection, something not as slow? And it seems as far as KVC goes is to either use 1) objc-runtime or 2) impose some client protocol on the conformer as ObjectMapper does

Comment: I use NSObject as the base type of the classes in https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection I'm sure there is no other way for setting values for a key. In most cases the speed of reflection is good enough. In your case you do a Mirror in your getValue function. Then it will execute each time you want to get a value. If you want to access multiple values, then you should also create a getValuesDictionary so that you can get the data from there.